# jQuery with disabled contents

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i have a problem with my jquery code which is disabling all the text after i click the next profile.

Fig.1 : you will notice here that i can highlight the text and highlight the scrollbar in first frame.

[image]

Fig.2 : you will notice here that none of all are highlighted.

[image]

here's the jquery source that im currently using.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.productList').hide(); // hide all details

    $('#thumbsets li').bind('click',function() {
        var tsLi = $(this).index(); // all elements have already an index
        $('.productList:eq('+ tsLi +')').siblings().fadeTo(400,0).end().fadeTo(400,1);
    });
});
```

i use this at all of my portfolio section. most of it are images. however, i tried to create a sample list of user profiles with this script function, but i found out that after my navigation switched to next profile member, it was already disabled (technically says, i can't scroll or highlight the text content).

is there possible way to adjust the script here? i doubt that the cause of my issue is:

```
            var tsLi = $(this).index(); // all elements have already an index
        $('.productList:eq('+ tsLi +')').siblings().fadeTo(400,0).end().fadeTo(400,1);
```

hope someone can help me about this. thanks in advance.

Comment: when you fade in the new profile, are you also setting a new z-index for it to place it on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fadeTo` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto) manipulates only the opacity. So the faded elements become invisible but are still there and on top of the other elements.. (*so you can not highlight those..*)

you should use [`fadeIn` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) and [`fadeOut` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) instead, because those will also hide/show the element as well..

```
$('.productList:eq('+ tsLi +')').siblings().fadeOut(400).end().fadeIn(400);
```